# What’s wrong with provided apex instance administrator password

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-apex, oracle-database-appliance, oracle-21c

1

I have installed Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition on Oracle windows 10 I am now trying to install Apex 22.2 .

Got to the chapter "5.4.2.3 Running apxchpwd.sql" to set the instance administrator password. Executed the @apxchpwd.sql command, it asks me for user name, e-mail and password but then it gives an error as quoted string not properly ended, also Tried various other passwords, nothing seems to be acceptable.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Did the text of the password include a quotation mark?

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL. I've removed those tags accordingly.

Comment: No, no any quotation mark